# Custom Hook State Change Not Updating All Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom hook defined as follows:

```js
export const useData = (): [boolean, () => Promise<void>] => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const fetch = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500)); // mock a network request timeout
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    return [isLoading, fetch];
};
```

I have two components, `A` and `B` that then use the hook as follows:

```js
const [ isLoading, fetch ] = useData();
```

My problem is when component `A` calls `fetch`, `isLoading` reflects the proper value in component `A` but not in Component `B`. In other words, `isLoading` is never updated in `B` when `fetch` is called by `A`. Am I missing something here?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are using `setState` which is a local state, what you need is a context alongside the hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is when component A calls fetch, isLoading reflects the
> proper value in component A but not in Component B. In other words,
> isLoading is never updated in B when fetch is called by A. Am I
> missing something here?

Yes, hooks are not meant to be used like that.
From docs:

> Do two components using the same Hook share state? No. Custom Hooks
> are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a
> subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you
> use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully
> isolated.

I think you must somehow combine your hook with `Context` API to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks this clarified things a lot. I read through the docs quickly but there is so much I'll admit I missed this :(

Comment: @SlothArmstrong Don't worry ;) I hope `Context` can help you.....maybe consume hook at top level and share data using `Context`.......

Comment: I created a top level component that does just that and it works great. Thanks again!